# Using send to call a method in a helper class

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am not sure why the code below is done this way, can someone take a look and see what is going on? **For example why in the send method below we are not sending the symbol?** or **Why we are not calling it directly somehow?**

```
describe Something do
  shared_examples 'for something' do
    context 'return 200 HTTP code' do
      it 'return the correct thing' do
        val = SomethingHelper.send(create_json)
      end  
    end
  end

  describe 'fddffsf' do
  it_behaves_like 'for something' do
    let(:create_json) {'create_json_hash'}
  end
end
```

And in the SomethingHelper we have a method named `create_population_management_hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shared example" is for multiple tests sharing similar environments. It helps you to avoid duplication.

For example, You have 'fddffsf' to test, and you may have more similar tests with the only difference at 'create_json'.

The reason why `create_json` dose not use symbol is, it used the variable defined by `let`

When you define a variable in `let`, you use symbol. And when you refer it, you need to use it without symbol.

Comment: It doesn't have a to be a `let`. It could be a method too. That's the beauty of using a bareword.